# Shadows issue in Unity

Tags: unity, lighting, shadows

I am using Unity Built-in render pipeline 2020.3.5

I have a weird shadow projection when pointing at game objects with my flashlight (spotlight). It looks like the shadow is floating or is another shadowing object attached to the real one. As can be seen in the video:

https://streamable.com/mnkw87

However I put a point light into the scene and the shadows work normal.
I have tried tweaking the cascades and the spotlight settings but didn't give me any results...
Any ideas what could it be?

Comment: It seems the light isn't coming from the torchlight but rather from a different position. Shadows look fine to me, though. Can you please attach a specific frame/screenshot to point out the issue more precisely?

Comment: The spotlight is coming from the tip of the flashlight. Here exactly: https://i.ibb.co/411x5z3/flashlight-spotlight.png

The shadow look like floating not on the wall or the floor where it should be. In this video you can see it better:
https://streamable.com/a69954

Comment: Shadow behave that way because the spotlight is integral with the flashlight, which is integral with the camera transform. Also, the light source could clip through geometry (causing the "glitch" in your second video) but you won't notice because of the rendering order you used for your first-person POV.